# Hibernate Projections - What is difference between Projections.property & Projections.groupProperty

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to java hibernate, I am unable to understand difference between Projections.property & Projections.groupProperty, both are giving same results. Please explain the difference and explain when to use each one.

Thanks.

Comment: See  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#property(java.lang.String). ( Roughly ) Projections.property  is for columns in select and Projections.groupProperty affects the group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groupProperty will be added to the `group by` clause of the SQL query